# PhpStorm Laravel Mamp issues

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

So I finally got artisan to work but I can't get the laravel installation to work. when i do 
php artisan migrate:install

it gives me this error:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I tried to change the database in the .env file and yes composer is installed and php artisan works properly.

I'm running mamp and phpstorm on windows so not from a virtual machine, and i want to link it to a database i made with mamp

so can someone help me with this issue?

best regards 
Ditger

Comment: What username/password did you put in .env?

Comment: Try changing the `DB_HOST` in the `.env` file to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: username is root
password is empty

Comment: changed the db host to 127.0.0.1 and i got this;
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` i
  nt unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character s
  et utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add .env

```
  DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
  DB_DATABASE=PUT-YOUR-DATABASE-NAME
  DB_USERNAME=root
  DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: appearently i mistyped something :/ failing is the best learning school thanks for the help

Comment: steady change ID and PW if you open website. thank you